# wordpress illegal string offset 'parameter' error

Tags: plugins, php, themes, html

I am getting the error illegal string offset when creating a checkbox in the admin.

my code look like this.

```
<input  type="checkbox"  id="slideThre" name="custom_settings[checked]" value="1" <?php checked(1, $custom_options['checked']);?>/>
```

There is no error when I check the box and save. The error appear when I uncheck the box and save.

What could be wrong?

thanks.

Comment: This is more a PHP question, debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes only send data when checked. When unchecked, there is no post (or get) data. You need to check if set using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['custom_settings']['checked'])) { /* it was ticked */ }
```